# CSS left and top property for an absolute positioned element does not calculate as expected for responsive design

Tags: jquery, css, html, dictionary, responsive-design

I have a responsive image with position relative in a parent container. In the same parent container I have a position: absolute pin over the image with a higher z-index value.

Pin shows up at a correct location on a static design but if I want to make it work for responsive, it looks like browser does not calculate the percentage properly and pin does not show up at a correct location.

To solve this issue, I have used jquery which calculates the responsive img size in pixels and also calculates the pin's css left and top positions in pixels. But this still does not work.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-12" id="map">
            <img src="../img/world-map.jpg" alt="world-map" id="world-map">
            <a href="#" class="sydney" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sydney-modal"></a>
            <a href="#" class="melbourne" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sydney-modal"></a>
            <a href="#" class="perth" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sydney-modal"></a>
            <a href="#" class="singapore" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sydney-modal"></a>
            <a href="#" class="hongkong" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sydney-modal"></a>
            <a href="#" class="india" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sydney-modal"></a>
            <a href="#" class="china" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sydney-modal"></a>
</div> <!-- end col map-->
```

Link to test page: http://test.nsg.unsw.edu.au/contact/

**LESS**

```
#map
    {
        position:relative;
        #world-map
        {
            width:100%;
            z-index:-100;               
        } //end word-map
        .sydney{
            position:absolute;
            width:12px;
            height:12px;
            background-color:red;
            /*left: 81.5%;
            top: 77.5%;*/
            }
    }
```

**Javascript solution**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('nav li:contains("Contact us")').addClass("active");

        //get width and height of image in px
        var imgWidth=$("#world-map").width();
        var imgHeight=$("#world-map").height();
        //console.log("image width x height ="+imgWidth+"x"+imgHeight);
        //change icon position according to the percantage of where location is found
        var sydneyLeft=0.815;
        var sydneyTop=0.775;
        //console.log("location left x top % ="+sydneyLeft+"x"+sydneyTop);
        var sydneyLeftpx=0.815*imgWidth;
        var sydneyToppx=0.775*imgHeight;
        //console.log("location left x top px ="+sydneyLeftpx+"x"+sydneyToppx);

        sydneyLeftpx=toInt(sydneyLeftpx);
        sydneyLeftpx=sydneyLeftpx-6; //location-pinwidth
        sydneyToppx=toInt(sydneyToppx);
        sydneyToppx=sydneyToppx-6; //location-pinheight

        //alert("location left x top px ="+sydneyLeftpx+"x"+sydneyToppx);

        $(".sydney").css({left: sydneyLeftpx+"px",
                        top: sydneyToppx+"px"               
            });

});
```

Note: I have not yet added a screen resize function for the javascript code and simply have been testing the code by refreshing the browser window.

Can some one please shed some light on why these values are not being calculated properly and how can i fix this issue?

Comment: nothing in css has height so calcs are likely done before image loads. Suggest setting height based on image aspect ratio

Comment: @charlietfl I am not sure what did you mean....I am already getting image height using jquery var imgHeight=$("#world-map").height();

Comment: but if image hasn't loaded it has no height at that time. _document.ready_ fires before images are loaded. However you know the aspect ratio of map image so you can check parent width and set accordingly

Comment: Sorry, do you mean I should calculate only the width under document.ready and then change the height according to aspect ratio? How would I calculate width if image is not loaded?

Comment: it will fill the parent won't it? Thus the width can be checked and used to set height

Comment: Made changes in Javascript as you said. But still does not work. http://test.nsg.unsw.edu.au/contact/index2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63686/discussion-between-umair-cheema-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

I wanted to create a html map tag like effect using img tag with a lesser z-index, and a pin/location over img tag.

I was able to do it successfully for static design but it did not work accordingly for the responsive design images. Initially, I tried to resolve this by using css percentage, but the pin/location position was always different with different screen sizes. I tried to fix the problem by calculating image aspect ratio and then change the pin location in pixels using Javascript. It did not work either.

**Solution**

I solved this problem using HTML map tag and area tag. I used a plugin from Matt Stow to make the map responsive.
http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html